# If $\gamma : \Delta^1 \rightarrow S^n$ is a "path" with $\gamma(e_1) = - \gamma(e_0)$, then $(1+a^n_*)\gamma$ is a $1$-cycle.

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

From Rotman's Algebraic Topology exercise $6.11$:

> If $\gamma : \Delta^1 \rightarrow S^n$ is a "path" with $\gamma(e_1) = - \gamma(e_0)$, then $(1+a^n_*)\gamma$ is a $1$-cycle, where $a^n$ represents the antipodal map.  Note:  By "path" we mean that $\sigma$ has domain $\Delta^1 = [-1, 1]$ instead of $I$.

I can see that I would need to show $\partial_1(1+a_*^n)\gamma = 0$.

This is $\partial_1 \gamma + \partial_1 a_*^n \gamma = 2\gamma(e_1) + \partial_1 a_*^n \gamma$, but how exactly would I evaluate this any further?

$f_*$ is usually denoted as a $H_n(f)$ for homology groups, so I'm not exactly sure how I would evaluate this.  Is there another more appropriate meaning for $a^n_*$?

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful that you don't confuse the negative of a $k$-simplex $\sigma$ in a chain group $C_k(S^n)$ with the negative of a map $\sigma: \Delta^k \to S^n$, that is, the map $s \mapsto a^n(\sigma(s))$. The former, which could be called the *algebraic negative* is just a formal operation in the group $C_k(S^n)$ without any geometric meaning. It merely adds a minus to the element $\sigma$, resulting in the element $-\sigma$ such that $\sigma+(-\sigma) = 0$. The latter, the *geometric negative* of the map $\sigma:\Delta^k \to S^n$ is the map sending each $s\in\Delta^k$ to the antipodal point of $\sigma(s)$ on the sphere. For points, the notations are indeed confusing, as a $0$-simplex in $S^n$ is simply written as a point $v$, and then $-v$ could mean either of the two negatives.

When you have an equation like
$$
\gamma(e_1) = -\gamma(e_0)
$$
however, there can be only one meaning, since both $\gamma(e_1)$ and $\gamma(e_0)$ are points on $S^n$, so $-\gamma(e_0)$ must mean a point on the sphere, as well.

For the actual computation of the boundary, note that $a^n$ is a continuous map $S^n \to S^n$, so it induces a chain map $a^n_*$ which commutes with the boundary operator $\partial$. Moreover, you have $\gamma(e_1) = a^n(\gamma(e_0))$.

I'm more used to the notation $f_\sharp$ for the chain map corresponding to the continuous map $f$, but I don't know which notation Rotman is using in his book.

---

**Edit:** The two concepts of *minus* described above are not completely independent. For example, when $n$ is even, and $c$ is a cycle in $S^n$ generating $H_n(S^n) \approx \mathbb Z$, then $a^n_*([c])$ is the negative of that generator, i.e. $a^n_*([c]) = -[c]$.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought that that symbol meant chain map.  So $\partial_1(1+a_*^n) \gamma = \gamma(e_1)-\gamma(e_0) + \partial_1 a^n_* \gamma = \gamma(e_1) + \gamma(e_1) + a_*^n(\gamma(e_1) + \gamma(e_1)) = \gamma(e_1) + \gamma(e_1) - \gamma(e_1) -\gamma(e_1)$.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I meant to say does $\gamma(e_1) + \gamma(e_1) - \gamma(e_1) - \gamma(e_1)$ make sense.

Comment: No, the boundary of $\gamma$ is not $2\gamma(e_1)$. That is because $\gamma(e_1)$ is not the negative of $\gamma(e_0)$ in $C_0(S^n)$, but rather the antipodal point of $\gamma(e_0)$, that is, $\gamma(e_1) = a^n(\gamma(e_0))$. That's what I wrote about in my answer. @OliverG